# nuget packages failing to download in VS 2019

Tags: .net-core, nuget, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore, proget

I am trying to restore packages for my .Net core solution from private proget server maintained by my organization using vpn. But it is not completing for last 7days due to some unknown network issues. I have tried with clearing the nuget cache, running `nuget restore`, `dotnet restore` and build solution. All came with same output.

The nuget package restore starts successfully, it downloads many packages, and then it fails with some random package. Some of the error logs that I have received are:

- Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsyncCore' for source 'https://proget.xxx.net/nuget/TestFeed/FindPackagesById()?id='packageName'&semVerLevel=2.0.0'.
- An error occurred while sending the request.
- Unable to connect to the remote server
- A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 127.0.0.1:8888

The nuget restore is working successfully for other devs. If it weren't, I could have concluded that it is an issue with the proget server. But now, I cannot decide whether it is an issue with my Visual studio 19, nuget config or system network. The url https://proget.xxx.net/ is opening successfully in my browser.

Any troubleshooting tips/logs to dig deep into the issue, or fixes are welcome.

Comment: Any idea where that `127.0.0.1:8888` address is coming from?

Comment: @n0rd: that's local proxy of the laptop I am using.

Answer (score 1):

It seemed like a network issue, nothing with any setup. I tried with `dotnet restore` to fetch all dependencies during idle hours, and it worked successfully. If someone has a better answer, please share.